# ansible playbooks get which variable file by default if not defined

Tags: variables, ansible

I have a devop directory containing ansible's varible directroy , plabooks and inventory directory

The directory looks like this

```
|groups_vars
      -all.yml
      -development.yml
      -staging.yml
|inventroy
      - staging
      - development

configure.yml
deploy.yml
```

configure.yml and deploy.yml contains task that are applied to either staging or development machines using variable in groups_vars

Know if i call ansible-playbook command with staging inventory. How will it know which variable file to use. The varfile task in not added to configure.yml and deploy.yml

By the way am using an example from the company i work and the example is working I just want to know the magic that is happening it is using the right variable file though the var file is not incuded in the configure.yml nor deploy.yml

Answer (score 1):

Ansible uses a few conventions to load vars files:

- group_vars/[group]
- host_vars/[host]

So if you have an inventory file that looks like this:

```
[staging]
some-host.name.com
```

Then These files will be included (optional extension .yml or .yaml also):

```
/group_vars/all
/group_vars/staging
/host_vars/some-host.name.com
```

I think this is the "magic" you are referring to.

You can find more on the subject here: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

And here: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html

Comment: new to Ansible, I know that vars_files & include_vars can be used to include variable files, is there a way to have each playbook load/import variables . specific to the playbook itself by default ?